# Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error"

Tags: apache, zend-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem, my server is running Zend 2, ubuntu, apache.
but now i want to change new server, but it not work. I'm a admin system not coder, pls help me this problem. thanks 
this is log:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:493 Stack trace: #0 /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #1 /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #2 /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) #3 /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRen in /home/forbesvn/websites/distribution.forbesvietnam.local/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 493

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .phtml file of the respective action and controller.
Suppose you are calling indexAction of IndexController inside the Album module then you need to create a index.phtml file inside the view folder (module->Album->view->album->index->index.phtml) file